# tf.gradients() returns a list of [None]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network, generative

Sorry if this sounds like a repeat. I have been through all of the related questions and found no suitable solutions to my problem's context.

I am trying to build a generative model that outputs probabilities for each tracked day of COVID to input into an SEIR-based epidemiology model.

The generation works. However, I cannot figure out how to train the model. I have to write a custom loss function that runs the day-by-day parameters through a step function for the epidemiology model with will populate a dataset of "confirmed" and "removed" for each day. I then compare that data to the recorded "confirmed" and "removed" from [John Hopkin's COVID dataset](https://github.com/datasets/covid-19/blob/main/data/worldwide-aggregate.csv) on GitHub.

I use Mean Absolute Error to calculate a loss between the "confirmed" and "removed" based on the generated probabilities and the actual values from the JHU dataset. The issue I am running into is when I call `the tf.gradient()` function it returns a list of `None`s. I am stuck here and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I am using:

**Training Step**

```py
# Define function to train the model based on one input
loss_fn = MeanAbsoluteError()
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.005)

@tf.function
def train_step(x, y):

  y_pred = np.zeros((3, latent_dim))

  N = tf.constant(int(7_000_000_000), dtype=tf.float64)
  E0 = tf.Variable(int(1000), trainable=False, dtype=tf.float64)
  I0 = tf.Variable(covid_df.iloc[0]["Confirmed"], trainable=False, dtype=tf.float64)
  R0 = tf.Variable(covid_df.iloc[0]["Removed"], trainable=False, dtype=tf.float64)
  S0 = tf.Variable(N - E0 - I0 - R0, trainable=False, dtype=tf.float64)
  u0 = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, dtype=tf.float64)

  SuEIRs = tf.stack([S0,u0,E0,I0,R0])

  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    logits = generator(tf.reshape(x, (batch_size, 4, latent_dim)), training=True)

    betas = logits[0][0]
    sigmas = logits[0][1]
    mus = logits[0][2]
    gammas = logits[0][3]

    for t in range(latent_dim):
      SuEIR_diffs = SuEIR_step(SuEIRs, t, N, betas, sigmas, mus, gammas)

      SuEIRs = SuEIRs + SuEIR_diffs

      confirmed = SuEIRs[3]
      removed = SuEIRs[4]

      # update y_pred
      y_pred[0,t] = float(t+1)
      y_pred[1,t] = confirmed.numpy()
      y_pred[2,t] = removed.numpy()

    # Convert predictions
    y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)

    # Calculate loss
    loss_value = loss_fn(y[1], y_pred[1]) + loss_fn(y[2], y_pred[2])

  # Calculate the gradient
  grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, generator.trainable_weights)

  print(grads) ##==>> outputs [None, None, None, None]

  # Apply gradients to model
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, generator.trainable_weights))
  return loss_value
```

**Training Loop**

```py
import time

epochs = 2
for epoch in range(epochs):
  print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))
  start_time = time.time()

  # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
  for step in range(sample_size):
    loss_value = train_step(x_input[step], y_true)

    # Log every 5 batches.
    if step % 5 == 0:
      print(
        "Training loss (for one batch) at step %d: %.4f"
        % (step, float(loss_value))
      )
    print("Time taken: %.2fs" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

**Error output**

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0'].
```

`loss_value` and `generator.trainable_weights` are populated as expected.

**EDIT:** Updated code to reflect the suggestions of [Myrl Marmarelis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66498964/12127309) and the architecture of [TensorFlow's custom training loop guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch#speeding-up_your_training_step_with_tffunction). Still having the same issue of gradients being a list of `None`'s.

Comment: Check if your loss function differentiable or not.

Comment: loss function is tf.MeanAbsoluteError() so it should be differentiable

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your calls to `np.array(...)` before calculating the loss (especially on `y_pred`) to `tf.convert_to_tensor(...)`. You need to build a proper symbolic graph by keeping everything as `tf.Tensor`s. In fact, make sure you are not converting anything to a non-Tensor anywhere along the chain of computation between the model parameters and the loss.

I would also suggest wrapping your training procedure in a `@tf.function` so that Tensorflow may compile it into a static graph.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and updated the code in my question to reflect the changes. However, the issue remains. Thank you for your answer, though. It was a very insightful rabbit hole to look into while researching `@tf.function`